# how to pause threading? and also send 5 userna at once

Tags: python

how to pause threading? and also send 5 username at once, after 5 username has been successfully sent it will pause, after a pause then continue sending data, until all username is successfully sent.

```
from threading import Thread 
import time 

def api_send_req(source): 
    print('started thread')
    print('sending 5 request to api')
    print('finish')


if __name__ == "__main__":

    try:

        list = "list.txt"
        mod = "r+"
        op = open(list, mod).readlines()
    
        for fr in op:

            x = fr.rstrip("\n")

            time.sleep(2)  

            t = threading.Thread(target=api_send_req, args=(x))
            t.start()

    except IOError as err:
        print("    ERROR -> "+str(err))
        exit()
    except EOFError as err:
        print("    ERROR -> "+str(err))
        exit()
    except IndexError as err:
        print("    ERROR -> "+str(err))
        exit()
    except KeyError as err:
        print("    ERROR -> "+str(err))
        exit()
    except KeyboardInterrupt as err:
        print("    [KILLED] By user")
        exit()
```

Comment: Hey, @john Son perhaps you should modify the description a bit. It's not clear `5 data of what`? Think clearly and shape your query accordingly then only will you receive better help.

Comment: @aamir maarofi 5 usernames I mean

Comment: You can use `t.join()` to allow the main thread to wait for another thread to finish. https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join It's worth saying that this somewhat defeats the point of using threads though, as you'd only ever have a single thread executing anything at given time.